# Get data from Current year and past two years

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get data from Current year and last three years. (2022,2021,2020, 2019)
I've a year field which is number.
For now I hard-coded value in my code as Year >= 2019.

I need help on how to make this dynamic so in future I just get data of past three years from the current year(included).
(Eg: If the current year is 2025, I will get data of 2025,2024,2023,2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable WHERE colyear >= YEAR( current_date() ) - 3;
```

CURRENT_DATE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_date.html

YEAR: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html

Comment: Hi @Gokhan, could you help me instead of the year if there is date like '2019-01-01' we need data for last two years.

Comment: @TechLearner there are plenty of options to produce it. E.g.: (YEAR( current_date() ) - 3) || '-01-01' etc...